# HTTP to HTTPS redirect for azure apim gateway url

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I want to force HTTPS on the gateway url of the Azure API Management services but there are no configuration settings for that.

By default, HTTPS is used by the browser but when I change it manually in the URL and switch to HTTP, I don't have a redirection to HTTPS which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a feedback request : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/37192618-block-http-and-or-force-https .
You may want to vote for it if it aligns with your requirement.

However, it is under review now and as workaround it is mentioned to use a policy at the global scope to check protocol and return a redirect if it’s http.